# What is the best way for deleting dynamic allocated memory of class member

Tags: c++

The following code is just a raw example reference. Everything works fine, but when the program is about to close it stuck for about a few seconds. It's all because of the wrong way of deleting memory I am assuming.
Please find below code snippet:

```
class Test {
private:
    static int count;
    static Test* arr;
public:
    int num;

    Test() {}

    Test(int val) : num(val) {
        arr[count] = *this;
        count++;
    }

    ~Test() {
        delete[] arr;
    }

    void print() {
        for (int a = 0; a <= count - 1; a++) {
            std::cout << arr[a].num << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int Test::count = 0;
Test* Test::arr = new Test[2];

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Test t1(10);
    Test t2(20);
    t2.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using a raw `new` and `delete` at all is the fundamental issue here. You have undefined behavior, because you are `delete`ing four times for one `new`....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use raw `new` and `delete` at all:

```
class Test {
private:
    static int count;
    static std::vector<Test> arr;
public:
    int num;

    Test() {}

    Test(int val) : num(val) {
        arr[count] = *this;
        count++;
    }

    // No user-defined destructor needed!

    void print() {
        for (int a = 0; a <= count - 1; a++) {
            std::cout << arr[a].num << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int Test::count = 0;
std::vector<Test> Test::arr{2};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Test t1(10);
    Test t2(20);
    t2.print();
    return 0;
}
```

(requires `#include<vector>`)

This does the same thing, but does not cause you any trouble with finding the correct place to `delete`. `std::vector` manages that for you.

Note however that whatever the purpose of this class is, it probably should not be limited in the number of `Test` it can create:

```
class Test {
private:
    static std::vector<Test> arr;
public:
    int num;

    Test() {}

    Test(int val) : num(val) {
        arr.push_back(*this); // Add new element!
    }

    // No user-defined destructor needed!

    void print() {
        for (int a = 0; a < arr.size(); a++) {
            std::cout << arr[a].num << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int Test::count = 0;
std::vector<Test> Test::arr; // Start empty!

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Test t1(10);
    Test t2(20);
    t2.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Now you aren't limited to using only two elements and you don't have to keep track of `count` either!

---

If you want to use `new` (which you shouldn't), then you need to call `delete[]` *exactly once* for each `new[]`.

In your code you call `new[]` *once* to initialize `arr` at program startup. You call `delete[]` each time a `Test` is destroyed and you have four `Test` instances in your program: 2 variables of type `Test` in `main` and 2 objects of type `Test` in the array that you allocate for `arr`. That means you are deleting the array pointed to by `arr` four times! That causes undefined behavior.

To do it correctly, you need to deallocate it *once*, when it is not needed anymore:

```
class Test {
private:
    static int count;
    static Test* arr;
public:
    int num;

    Test() {}

    Test(int val) : num(val) {
        arr[count] = *this;
        count++;
    }

    // No user-defined destructor needed!

    void print() {
        for (int a = 0; a <= count - 1; a++) {
            std::cout << arr[a].num << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int Test::count = 0;
Test* Test::arr = new Test[2]; // Executed once at startup

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Test t1(10);
    Test t2(20);
    t2.print();

    delete[] arr; // We don't need the array anymore, so `delete[]` it *once*

    return 0;
}
```

---

Please also note that I doubt the you are approaching whatever problem you actually have the correct way with the design of this class. If your intention is to register all objects of type `Test` that are created in a global registry, then you should be warned that you are saving *copies* of the `Test` objects in `arr`.

Discussing other approaches to such a problem is out-of-scope of the question, especially if I don't know the actual intended use. So I will stop here.

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the static memory in `arr` multiple times which leads to undefined behavior.